# Mean of Absolute differences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a programme in Python 3which calculates the mean of the absolute differences between successive values.

Comment: `r = sum_dif //(len(v)-1)` shouldn't be in the scope of the for loop. Also `//` as opposed to `/` is integer division. In your example using `/` makes more sense, I guess

Comment: `//` is the integer ("floor") division, e.g. `0.7 // 10` will give you `0.0`. You need to use just `/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** As the code was removed from the question, updating answer, moving the issues with code to bottom.

As given in comments you can use `enumerate()` to get the index as well as element from the array and then use that to calculate the mean. Example -

```
>>> def absolute_difference(v):
...     sum_diff = 0
...     for i,x in enumerate(v):
...         if i+1 < len(v):
...             sum_diff += abs(v[i+1] - x)
...     r = sum_diff/len(v)
...     return r
...
>>> absolute_difference([4.0, 4.2, 4.1, 4.4, 4.3])
0.1400000000000004
```

---

Lots of issues in the code (that you seem to have removed) -

1. Why are you converting your absolute difference to `float` ? float mathematics is not accurate , as you can see from the sum of difference  in your code - `0.20000000000000018` . In your case you do not need to convert them to float.
2. The main issue of `0.0` for `r` occurs because you are using `//` to divide, `//` truncates the division to the nearest integer, so diving `7.0` by something grater than that using `//` would always result in `0.0` . Example -

   ```
   >>> 7.0 // 8.0
   0.0
   >>> 7.0/8.0
   0.875
   ```

   For your case, you should divide using `/` .
3. You are taking the mean in each iteration of the loop, though that is not an issue , it may not be completely needed. If you do not want to take the mean in each iteration of the loop, you should indent it outside the loop.

Comment: The OP needs pairs of values so is using the index. They should probably `enumerate`, or could use the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe from `itertools`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `//` which means integer division in python 3

That is

**i.e)**

```
2/4 =0.5

2//4=0
```

Just replace the `//` with `/` when calculating r

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
def absolute_difference(values):
    last = values[0]
    total = 0

    for value in values[1:]:
        total += abs(value - last)
        last = value

    return total/(len(values)-1)

print('{:.5f}'.format(absolute_difference([4.0, 4.2, 4.1, 4.4, 4.3])))
```

Giving the answer: `0.17500`

Answer (score 0):

Also, to prevent `None` from appearing at the end, you must have `return` at the end of your definition. This happens if you make another variable "equal to" (`=`) your definition. This was shown in the other posts, but I'm stating this just to highlight things out.